# Force a button to open in a new window

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with Java and trying to force a click to open a new window.  I can't use a contextClick because the option to open the link doesn't exist if I right-click the image button.  Any ideas on how this can be done using Wedbriver?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider pressing the Ctrl button and later performing the click activity.
Code Example

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("CHOOSE_YOUR_XPATH_HERE")); //Choose best way of selecting WebElement
element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL);
element.click();
```

Hope this works for you